# Saying its running hot but full of coolant and not over heating

Tags: engine, coolant, hyundai, hvac, elantra

2005  Hyundai Elantra. Says its running hot but has coolant and so far hasn't over heated and also can't turn on heat in car because smoke pours from vents into the inside of car.

Comment: Are you sure it's smoke, could it be antifreeze steam?

Comment: does smoke come from the vents when the temperature is set to cool?  If not your heater core is likely bad.  This can cause coolant loss and air bubbles in the coolant system.

Comment: Is there any water/coolant on the floor of your passenger side within the vehicle?

Comment: Voting to close, question is too broad (undefined) and OP hasn't responded to comments.